# Как сделать мульзагрузку файлов для формы?

Tags: массивы, php, изображения, html

Вот input поле: `<input class="filestyle" name="attachfile[]" multiple="true" type="file" >`
Каким образом извлечь картинки из массива?

```
<? 
    } 
    function complete_mail() { 
            // $_POST['title'] содержит данные из поля "Тема", trim() - убираем все лишние пробелы и переносы строк, htmlspecialchars() - преобразует специальные символы в HTML сущности, будем считать для того, чтобы простейшие попытки взломать наш сайт обломались, ну и  substr($_POST['title'], 0, 1000) - урезаем текст до 1000 символов. Для переменных $_POST['mess'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['tel'], $_POST['email'] все аналогично 
            $_POST['name'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name'])), 0, 1000); 
            $_POST['tel'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['tel'])), 0, 1000); 
            $_POST['email'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email'])), 0, 30); 
            $_POST['pass'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['pass'])), 0, 30); 
            $_POST['address'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['address'])), 0, 50); 
            $_POST['spec'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['spec'])), 0, 50); 
            $_POST['time'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['time'])), 0, 50); 
            $_POST['region'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['region'])), 0, 50); 
            $_POST['info'] =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['info'])), 0, 50);

            // обратите внимание, теперь мы можем писать красивые письма, с помощью html тегов ;-) 
            $mess = ' 
    <b>Имя отправителя:</b>'.$_POST['name'].'<br /> 
    <b>Контактный телефон:</b>'.$_POST['tel'].'<br /> 
    <b>Контактный email:</b>'.$_POST['email'].'<br /> 
    <b>Пароль:</b>'.$_POST['pass'].'<br /> 
    <b>Адрес:</b>'.$_POST['adress'].'<br /> 
    <b>Специлизация:</b>'.$_POST['spec'].'<br /> 
    <b>Время работы:</b>'.$_POST['time'].'<br /> 
    <b>Регион:</b>'.$_POST['region'].'<br /> 
    <b>Информация о бизнесе:</b>'.$_POST['info'].'<br /> 
    '.$_POST['mess'];

            // подключаем файл класса для отправки почты 
            require 'class.phpmailer.php';

            $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
            $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
            $mail->From = 'contact@kolody-s.com';      // от кого 
            $mail->FromName = 'contact@kolody-s.com';   // от кого 
            $mail->AddAddress('contact@kolody-s.com', 'Имя'); // кому - адрес, Имя 
            $mail->IsHTML(true);        // выставляем формат письма HTML 
            $mail->Subject = 'Заявка с сайта youfinpro/registration'; // тема письма

            // если был файл, то прикрепляем его к письму 
            if(isset($_FILES['attachfile'])) { 
                     if($_FILES['attachfile']['error'] == 0){ 
                        $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachfile']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['attachfile']['name']); 
                     } 
            } 
            // если было изображение, то прикрепляем его в виде картинки к телу письма. 
            if(isset($_FILES['attachimage'])) { 
                     if($_FILES['attachimage']['error'] == 0){ 
                        if (!$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($_FILES['attachimage']['tmp_name'], 'my-attach', 'image.gif', 'base64', $_FILES['attachimage']['type'])) 
                             die ($mail->ErrorInfo); 
                        $mess .= '<b>Фото:</b><br /><img src="cid:my-attach" border=0><br />'; 
                     } 
            } 
            $mail->Body = $mess;

            // отправляем наше письмо 
            if (!$mail->Send()) die ('Mailer Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo); 
            echo 'Спасибо! Ваше письмо отправлено.'; 
            header("Location: /registration/");
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) complete_mail(); 
    else show_form(); 
    ?>
```

Comment: > Каким образом извлечь картинки из массива?

Вы не знаете, как работать с массивом? Или циклы еще не проходили?

Comment: странно, http://www.php-mail.ru/?id=4 

тот же код, только вопрос другой ))))

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="files[]" type="file"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files'][0]['tmp_name'], 'ПУТЬ');
?>
```

Может это владелец php-mail.ru ? :D

Comment: @Iranda, это вы добавили в ответ про владельца php-mail.ru? Круто!)))

Comment: @Deus, от себя к контенту я ничего никогда не добавляю :)